# Aerospike's behavior on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, nosql, key-value, aerospike

In my test setup on EC2 I have done following:

1. One Aerospike server is running in ZoneA (say Aerospike-A).
2. Another node of the same cluster is running in ZoneB (say Aerospike-B).
3. The application using above cluster is running in ZoneA.
4. I am initializing AerospikeClinet like this:

   ```
   hosts= new Host[];
   hosts[0] = new Host(PUBLIC_IP_OF_AEROSPIKE-A, 3000);
   AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient(policy, hosts);
   ```

With above setup I am getting below behavior:

1. Writes are happening on both Aerospike-A and Aerospike-B.
2. Reads are only happening on Aerospike-A (data is around 1million records, occupying 900MB of memory and 1.3 GB of disk)

   ```
   Question: Why are reads not going to both the nodes?
   ```
3. If I take Aerospike-B down, everything works perfectly. There is no outage.
4. If I take Aerospike-A down, all the writes and reads start failing. I've waited for 5 mins for other node to take traffic but it didn't work.

   ```
   Questions: 
   a. In above scenario, I would expect Aerospike-B to take all the traffic. But this is not happening. Is there anything I am doing wrong?
   b. Should I be giving both the hosts while initializing the client?
   c. I had executed "clinfo -v 'config-set:context=service;paxos-recovery-policy=auto-dun-all'" on both the nodes. Is that creating a problem?
   ```

Comment: How do you know that the writes are going to Aerospike-B from the client ? Aerospike server can do internal proxy to other nodes and may create objects there. But this does not mean that the client is able to write to Aerospike-B. I am guessing that the client is not able to contact Aerospike-B.

Comment: I was using `clmonitor` to check `latency`. I added both `Host`s to the Host array while initializing the client and now everything is working ok!

Comment: You do not need to add both the hosts in the array. The aerospike client should be able discover all the nodes of the cluster if everything is ok. After this reads/writes should go to both the nodes.

Comment: Apparently this problem went away after adding both the hosts in the array. I was using version 3.0.6 of the (java) client.

Answer (score 1):

In EC2 you *should* place all the nodes of the cluster in the same AZ of the same region. You *can* use the [rack awareness](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/rack-aware.html) feature to set up nodes in two separate AZs, however you will be paying with a [latency hit](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/rack-aware-feature-is-not-currently-available-for-replication-factor-greater-than-2/879/4) on each one of your writes.

Now what your seeing is [likely due to misconfiguration](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/issues/56#issuecomment-117901128). Each EC2 machine has a public IP and a local IP. Machines sitting on the same subnet may access each other through the local IP, but a machine from a different AZ cannot. You need to make sure your `access-address` is set to the public IP in the event that your cluster nodes are spread across two availability zones. Otherwise you have clients which can reach some of the nodes, lots of proxy events as the cluster nodes try to compensate and move your reads and writes to the correct node for you, and weird issues with data upon nodes leaving or joining the cluster.

For more details:

- http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/general/
- https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/issues/56#issuecomment-117901128